# How to find all duplicate documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates

We have a need to walk over all of the documents in our AWS ElasticSearch cluster, version 6.0, and gather a count of all the duplicate user ids.
I have tried using a Data Visualization to aggregate counts on the user ids and export them, but the numbers don't match another source of our data that is searchable via traditional SQL. 
What we would like to see is like this:
USER ID   COUNT
userid1   4
userid22  3
...
I am not an advanced Lucene query person and have yet to find an answer to this question. If anyone can provide some insight into how to do this, I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 9):

The following query will count each id, and filter the ids which have <2 counts, so you'll get something in the likes of:

> id:2, count:2
>
> id:4, count:15

```
GET /index
{
    "query":{
        "match_all":{}
    },
    "aggs":{
        "user_id":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"user_id",
                "size":100000,
                "min_doc_count":2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More here:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get all duplicate userids with count

First you get to know maximum size of aggs. 
   find all maximum matches record via aggs cardinality.

```
GET index/type/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "maximum_match_counts": {
         "cardinality": {
            "field": "userid",
            "precision_threshold": 100
         }
      }
   }
}
```

get value of maximum_match_counts aggregations

Now you can get all duplicate userids

```
GET index/type/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "userIds": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "userid",
            "size": maximum_match_counts,
            "min_doc_count": 2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: when you set size more than 10K you will get a warning about this approach will throw an error for the feature releases. which means you will not able to find all duplicate documents. this is not a right way to achieve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you go with terms aggregation ([Bharat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49370085/889556) suggestion) and set aggregation size more than 10K you will get a warning about this approach will throw an error for the feature releases.

Instead of using terms aggregation you should go with [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) to scan all of your documents by pagination/afterkey method.

> the composite aggregation can be used to paginate all buckets from a multi-level aggregation efficiently. This aggregation provides a way to stream all buckets of a specific aggregation similarly to what scroll does for documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /index

{
    "query":{
        "match_all":{}
    },
    "aggs":{
        "user_id":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"user_id",
                "size":65536,
                "min_doc_count":2
            }
        }
    }
}

this one is working perfectly, i have found issues in lot of end point ES url's using this query, this will help you in post man, postman will display an error if you run the query with size 100000,so better you can use size=65536, and you have to replace the  "field":"user_id" name as well,it should be your field name
```